# Python with beautiful UI + glass effect

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm a new in Python.
I would like to know can I create good interface on python, something like WPF? 
I didn't find any glass effect with PyQt. It's really important for my decision.
Thanks.

I'm sorry that I didn't give a lot of details. I need to port WPF app to python. The main goal I still need a good UI. Can I make something like this 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightGlassOrbButton.aspx?msg=3170079
on python? Can I use different styles for mouseover and normal state?

Comment: I would accept previous answers, so users are more inclined to answer your question.

Comment: Also, can you show an example of what you mean? I'm pretty sure both of those use the system defaults.

Comment: FYI http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/09/15/using-blur-behind-on-windows/

Answer (score 3):

Glass effect is probably a Qt skin and has nothing to do with Python in particular. People say that [there's a tutorial for Qt skinning](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/is-it-possible-to-skin-qt-4-5-such-that-it-has-a-game-like-interface). I failed to quickly google a ready-made glass-like skin, though.

Answer (score 2):

Also, in the new QT RC there is a new support system for GUI related stuff. QML it is called, and examples can be found [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeexamples.html). I do not know if it alreade wrapped in PyQT but I suppose it is possible to use it in combination with PyQT.

[image: example glowy things]
[image: flickr example]

Answer (score 1):

If glass effect = transparency, then Qt supports this, but it requires a special flag set on the window. See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq16-background.html for some examples.

If you want a blurred background, then I doubt it can be done as easily, since not many GUI-frameworks that Qt supports do compositing like Vista & Win7, so it's probably hard to abstract into a cross-platform toolkit.

But simpler things might be possible, and with QGraphicsScene, you can do a lot of these things yourself (but not w.r.t. the window's background, IIUC).

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't give a lot of details. I need to port WPF app to python. The main goal I still need a good UI. Can I make something like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightGlassOrbButton.aspx?msg=3170079 on python? Can I use different styles for mouseover and normal state?

Comment: @Artyom: Yes, `QStyle` allows you to draw your button differently depending on state, so that should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no luck with Qt, [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) can do it. See [How to draw a transparent frame in wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740993/how-to-draw-a-transparent-frame-in-wxpython).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the fluent app library

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33061359)