# How to create a transparent frame with visible borders?

Tags: python, wxpython

I would like to create a transparent frame with visible borders. The code I've written based on hasenj's work of 'shaped-frame' (http://hasenj.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/making-a-fancy-window-in-wxpython/) is as follows. But I still have problem making one. I must have missed something. Could anybody point out what's wrong with the program? Thanks.

---

```
import wx

class FancyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, style = wx.STAY_ON_TOP | 
                          wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR | wx.FRAME_SHAPED,
                          size=(width, height))
        self.SetTransparent(50)
        b = wx.EmptyBitmap(width, height)
        dc = wx.MemoryDC()
        dc.SelectObject(b)
        dc.SetBrush(wx.TRANSPARENT_BRUSH)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 2))
        dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, width, height)
        dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
        self.SetShape(wx.RegionFromBitmap(b))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyDown)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnKeyDown(self, event):
        """quit if user pressEsc"""
        if event.GetKeyCode() == 27: #27 is the Esc key
            self.Close(force=True)
        else:
            event.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    FancyFrame(300, 300)
    app.MainLoop()
```

---

Answer (score 2):

It is not very good idea to draw stuff outside MainLoop. You should setup your wx application so it is Event driven. The events EVT_PAINT and EVT_SIZE should be handled. The `wx.Timer` can be used for basic movement.

```
import wx

#============================================================================= 
class DrawPanelDB(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.ballPosition = [20, 20]
        self.ballDelta = [1, 1]

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTime, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(20)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(wx.BLACK))
        dc.Clear()
        dc.DrawCirclePoint(self.ballPosition, 20)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnSize(self, event):
        self.Refresh()
        self.Update()

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnEraseBackground(self, event):
        pass # Or None  

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnTime(self, event):
        self.ballPosition[0] += self.ballDelta[0]
        self.ballPosition[1] += self.ballDelta[1]
        w, h = self.GetClientSizeTuple()
        if self.ballPosition[0] > w:
            self.ballPosition[0] = w
            self.ballDelta[0] *= -1
        if self.ballPosition[1] > h:
            self.ballPosition[1] = h
            self.ballDelta[1] *= -1
        if self.ballPosition[0] < 0:
            self.ballPosition[0] = 0
            self.ballDelta[0] *= -1
        if self.ballPosition[1] < 0:
            self.ballPosition[1] = 0
            self.ballDelta[1] *= -1       
        self.Refresh()

#============================================================================= 
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = DrawPanelDB(self)
        self.Show()

#============================================================================= 
app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

---

**Edit:** Example with ScreenDC using xor function for non-destructible drawing.

```
import wx

#============================================================================= 
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.ballPosition = [20, 20]
        self.lastPosition = None
        self.ballDelta = [1, 1]

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTime, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(20)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnTime(self, event):
        self.ballPosition[0] += self.ballDelta[0]
        self.ballPosition[1] += self.ballDelta[1]
        w, h = wx.DisplaySize()
        if self.ballPosition[0] > w:
            self.ballPosition[0] = w
            self.ballDelta[0] *= -1
        if self.ballPosition[1] > h:
            self.ballPosition[1] = h
            self.ballDelta[1] *= -1
        if self.ballPosition[0] < 0:
            self.ballPosition[0] = 0
            self.ballDelta[0] *= -1
        if self.ballPosition[1] < 0:
            self.ballPosition[1] = 0
            self.ballDelta[1] *= -1       

        dc = wx.ScreenDC()
        dc.StartDrawingOnTop()
        dc.SetLogicalFunction(wx.XOR) 
        if self.lastPosition is not None:
            dc.DrawRectangle(self.lastPosition[0], self.lastPosition[1], 15, 15)
        self.lastPosition = (self.ballPosition[0], self.ballPosition[1])
        dc.DrawRectangle(self.ballPosition[0], self.ballPosition[1], 15, 15)    
        dc.EndDrawingOnTop()

#============================================================================= 
app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

---

**Edit:** Another possibility is to keep backup copy of that part of the screen.

```
import wx

#============================================================================= 
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.ballPosition = [20, 20]
        self.lastPosition = None
        self.ballDelta = [1, 1]
        self.patch = wx.EmptyBitmap(20, 20)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTime, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(20)

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnTime(self, event):
        self.ballPosition[0] += self.ballDelta[0]
        self.ballPosition[1] += self.ballDelta[1]
        w, h = wx.DisplaySize()
        if self.ballPosition[0] > w:
            self.ballPosition[0] = w
            self.ballDelta[0] *= -1
        if self.ballPosition[1] > h:
            self.ballPosition[1] = h
            self.ballDelta[1] *= -1
        if self.ballPosition[0] < 0:
            self.ballPosition[0] = 0
            self.ballDelta[0] *= -1
        if self.ballPosition[1] < 0:
            self.ballPosition[1] = 0
            self.ballDelta[1] *= -1       

        dc = wx.ScreenDC()
        dc.StartDrawingOnTop()

        bdc = wx.MemoryDC(self.patch)
        if self.lastPosition is not None:
            dc.Blit(self.lastPosition[0] - 2, self.lastPosition[1] - 2, 20, 20, bdc, 0, 0)
        bdc.Blit(0, 0, 20, 20, dc, self.ballPosition[0] - 2, self.ballPosition[1] - 2)
        self.lastPosition = (self.ballPosition[0], self.ballPosition[1])

        dc.DrawRectangle(self.ballPosition[0], self.ballPosition[1], 15, 15)    
        dc.EndDrawingOnTop()

#============================================================================= 
app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Well, I do need to draw *on the screen* because I am implementing a virtual mouse. What I intend to do is to have the program repeatedly draw rectangles or lines on the screen until the user press the button of a special one-key device (this is for hand-disabled people), which signifies that the user want to move the mouse to the position on the screen.

Comment: @yltang - I have added another example with drawing on screen instead of window. I did not find a way how to invalidate part of screen to force it redrawn however, so I had to use xor function.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a transparent window (`window.SetTransparent(0)`), and placing a bitmap on it that you draw to yourself (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740993/how-to-draw-a-transparent-frame-in-wxpython/748302#748302) for example).

Then you would set an event handler for mouse move, and move around the window with the cursor. Also set a timer, so that you can fade out the bitmap if the mouse doesn't move for x seconds.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I've written some code based on hasenj's work. However, I still have problem showing red borders on a transparent rectangle. Since the system doesn't let me paste the whole program (about 30 lines) here. Is it possible that I send my program to you and you might check what's wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but the system is weird. If I type the the "enter" key, my message will be saved and posted, just the same as if I click the "Add comment" (or "Save Edits") button. Hence, I can't add blank lines. Moreover, if I copy my program and paste it here (the system does let me paste), nothing happens if I click the "Add comment" (or "Save Edits") button -- I can't post the message. What can I do?

Comment: @yltang - I did not mean to put the code in a comment comment, but edit your question on the top.